# ExtJs deleting element from store doesn't work

Tags: javascript, rest, store, extjs6

I'm working with ExtJs 6.2.0 and Java Spring MVC for the REST API.
I'm trying to delete an object from one of my store but I'm having a problem : instead of using my id named `idCamp`, extjs is using the field named `id` that contains an extjs generated id (for example: `extModel47-1`).

I'm working on the delete part but I didn't try to update a camp nor fetch one, but I think the configuration is the same for these three operations that need the id.

Here is my store:

```
Ext.define('XXXXXX.store.Camps', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.camps',
    model: 'XXXXXX.model.Camp',
    fields: [
        'idCamp', // More irrelevant fields
    ],
    autoLoad : true,
    autoSync: true,
    storeId: 'storeCamp',
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        idParam: 'idCamp',
        url: // irrelevant,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'data'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

Here is my model:

```
Ext.define('XXXXXX.model.Camp', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'idCamp',
    fields: [
        { name: 'idCamp', type: 'int' },
        // More irrelevant fields
    ]
});
```

I also tried to put an idProperty inside the writer/reader inside the proxy but it didn't do anything.

Forgive my poor usage of the English language since I'm a French people.

Best regards,
Morony

Comment: so you need to use idCamp as id and go over the record id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is using a combination of fields/model in your store definition. They are in competition with each other. Remove the `fields` definition.

Comment: Thanks! You've found my mistake I'm very grateful!